# Atribuir resultado de consulta MySQL a uma variável PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Como que, depois de contar quantos registos tenho num banco de dados, como faço para colocar o valor dentro de uma variavél PHP:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql); 
$total = $row['COUNT(*)'];
```

Eu consegui fazer o que queria assim, mas isto é correto de se fazer? Tem alguma forma melhor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está correto a forma que você desenvolveu, alias, pode utilizar outros tipos de retornos que espera como Objeto, Associativo ou Array.

Exemplos

```
    //Objeto
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
          echo $row->column1;
          echo $row->column2;
      }



    //Associativo
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo $row["column1"];
          echo $row["column2"];
      }



     //Array
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo $row[0];
          echo $row[1] ;
       }
```

Answer (score 4):

Adicione a query um alias para a coluna desejada. Por exemplo:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registros FROM `users`");
```

Depois, basta selecionar o alias que você utilizou:

```
$total = $row['total_registros'];
```